# Fastapi SqlAlchemy session returns an empty object?But when I print it its actual data there

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

My app uses `fastapi==0.109.2` with `SQLAlchemy==2.0.27`.
So my sql connection and session worked fine but I got some errors from sqlalchemy and I changed the way im connecting to use contextmanager like so:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def session_scope():
    db_engine = create_engine(url) # echo=True if needed to see background SQL        
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        print("Error")
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

I then Import it and use it here, as you can see I have 2 prints there, the first one shows the actual data, the second one (which is what the endpoint is returning) is emtpy object and I cant seem to find the issue...

```
@router.get("/me")
def getusers(dependencies=Depends(JWTBearer())):
    user = None
    with session_scope() as sess:
        x = sess.query(TokenTable).where(TokenTable.access_toke == dependencies).first()
        user = sess.query(User).where(User.id == x.user_id).first()
        print(user.__dict__)
    print(user.__dict__)
    return user
```

The logs:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:40662 - "GET /users/me HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f11ef2bfc40>, 'first': 'Deez', 'last': 'Nuts', 'email': 'test2@test.com', 'id': 2, 'is_active': True, 'coach': None}
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f11ef2bfc40>}
INFO:     127.0.0.1:40662 - "GET /users/1/logs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:40656 - "GET /users/me HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

I read alot of the sqlachemy documentation, found a few questions here as well, but none of them covered this particular topic.

Comment: The second `__dict__` is empty because the object is expired after the session is committed or rolled back, as described in the answer to the linked duplicate. There is some discussion in the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_state_management.html#refreshing-expiring).